# Python image creation loops

Tags: python, image, loops

This code below creates a 1D image of a race track:

```
def displayTrack(position):

    output=''#value given to output
    track=[' ']*20# track is initially just a bunch of empty spaces
    track[position]= 'r'#AND track also contains an r icon
    print(' -'*20)#these are the top and bottom borders
    print('0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 A B C D E F G H I J')#these represent each individual cell


    for i in range(len(track)):
        output= output +track[i] +'|'#append a "|" before and after each empty space " "
    print (output)#print the result
    print(' -'*20)
```

If you run this code you will be able to view the image. If you look at the charachter "r" you will see that to the right of charachter "r" there is "|" character. I need to implement a "|" on the left side of runner as well. I need to use a method similar to above because the initial states of many of the variables and the image depends on other variables,etc.

I know the problem exists in the fate that output= ''. If instead output was not a space, or not a charachter at all then the image would display properly but I do not know how to make it so. Can someone please give me a hand. Any and all help is appreciated.

If anything is unclear please let me know an I will change it as soon as possible.

EDIT: So I figured out that the new code should look something like this: There are 3 changes:

1) output='|' instead of ''
2) in the strings that contain the hyphens as well as the alphanumeric charachters, the space at the end is moved to the beginning instead. This fixes all the problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want ? It is unclear, since your original layout is strange.

```
def displayTrack(position):

    output='|'#value given to output
    track=[' ']*20# track is initially just a bunch of empty spaces
    track[position]= 'r'#AND track also contains an r icon
    print(' -'*20)#these are the top and bottom borders
    print(' 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 A B C D E F G H I J')#these represent each individual cell

    for i in range(len(track)):
        output= output +track[i] +'|'#append a "|" before and after each empty space " "
    print (output)#print the result
    print(' -'*20)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your comment #append a "|" before and after each empty space " " is misleading. What the statement before it does, is add a part of the track and a "|". It doesn't look if the character is a space, and doesn't put anything before it. The only reason there are |'s before the spaces is because they follow a position which has one after it.

To put something before the rest, start with output = '|' instead of ''. You may want to put an extra space before the other lines as well in that case, to keep things lined up. For example: print (' ' + ' -' * 20)

Comment: Yup I just figured that out before looking at this. The new code will be in the OP soon. sorry for misleading you.